# How to derive a certain determinantal identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Does anybody know how to derive

$$\det(\mathbf A)\cdot \det(\mathbf D + \mathbf E \cdot \mathbf A^{-1} \cdot \mathbf B) = \det(\mathbf D)\cdot \det(\mathbf A + \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf D^{-1} \cdot \mathbf E)$$

where $\mathbf A$, $\mathbf B$, $\mathbf C$, $\mathbf D$, $\mathbf E$ are non-singular matrices?

Most likely, it requires the [Sylvester determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_determinant_theorem) theorem).

Comment: I don't think this can be true: the right side is $\det D \det B \det D^{-1} \det E = \det B \det E$, which is independent of $D$.  If we take $D = -EA^{-1}B$ then the left side is 0.

Comment: I must have made a mistake with putting the formula in the form, now the correct one in the question body

Comment: also thanks for putting that in latex

Comment: You can prove it just by using $\det{X\cdot Y}=\det{X}\det{Y}$ and usual multiplication rules for matrices.

Comment: One might get started with the special case $A=D=I$, proving:  
$$det(I+EB)=det(I+BE)$$  
for any invertible matrices $B,E$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\det(A)\cdot\det(D+E\cdot A^{-1}\cdot B) & = \det(A)\cdot\det(D)\cdot\det(1+D^{-1}\cdot E\cdot A^{-1}\cdot B) \\
& = \det(A)\cdot\det(D)\cdot\det(B)\cdot\det(B^{-1}+D^{-1}\cdot E\cdot A^{-1}) \\
& = \det(A)\cdot\det(D)\cdot\det(1+B\cdot D^{-1}\cdot E\cdot A^{-1}) \\
& = \det(D)\cdot\det(A+B\cdot D^{-1}\cdot E)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 8):

A neat way to prove this is by observing that these are two ways to write the determinant of the block matrix
$$ \pmatrix{ A & B \\ -E & D } $$
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)

---

The proof using Sylvester's determinant theorem is done by simply plugging in the right "pairs" of matrices into the right spots.
That is, given the theorem as
$$ \det(I_p + XY ) = \det(I_n + YX) $$
Just let $X = EA^{-1}$ and $Y = BD^{-1}$. From there I think you can figure it out on your own.

Comment: In the first part of this answer there is a sign difference to be accounted for in comparing the determinant of the block matrix to the expressions matcheek asks about.

Comment: @hardmath Good catch. Corrected.